# I need help on a really simple thing

Tags: objective-c

How to build an interface like [this](http://www.macstories.net/wp-content/uploads/u1/Twitterrific%204.4.3/Twitterrific%204.4.3%20Use%20Last%20Photo.PNG)?

I noticed I have no idea how to google search for this thing....

Comment: Thanks for the -1 point from don't know who...

Comment: Check out [this example](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/).

Comment: @dunforget Didn't downvote but was tempted to do because questions with the whole content sitting somewhere else don't really fit in here.

Comment: sorry for that. was in a hurry to know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an action sheet. Use [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you're developing for iOS, you should really read the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html). That way you will not only know what are the correct principles to use when designing the user interface, but you'll also know the names of all the UI elements.